# Unity unable to change android icon

Tags: unity, android

Hi I've have spent the past few days googling how to do this and I'm making no progress. I have created a png image for each of the sized icon 36x36, 48x48, 72x72,96x96, 144x144 & 192x192. But when I load my app on any device the default icon apps. This is preventing me from uploading my game to the store as I don't want users to have a game with no icon.

Can anyone help get these icons to actually appear. I have tried different devices, uninstalling the app and reinstalling but still no luck. Do the images have to be a certain format, or any setting need selecting with in unity to make them compatible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I haven't had this problem before. Did you recompile after adding the icons?

Comment: @Draco18s Hi, yes cleaned the solution and rebuilt.

Comment: have you added it to the player settings ?

Comment: @uri hi yep that's the only place I know where it can be done

Comment: Try changing the package name and then install on your device with the APK. When you uninstall an app on android, it doesn't truly uninstall everything right away. Some things get cached.

Comment: @TartleWizard no luck with that. Even installed it on a brand new device and it still doesn't show the images. I feel like I've done everything correct, So fustrating getting stuck on something that seems so simple.

Comment: @Phil3992 can you share screens of how you set it up and so on or even better can you upload the project somewhere so I can play with it and figure out what is going on.

Comment: @UriPopov I have uploaded images of my uploads and an example of there settings in the folder.

Comment: Well... This seem in order. I mean the texture type is wrong but I tried building my project with that setting and it worked. Are you building with gradel or the internal builder? Also what version of unity are you using. Try upgrading if you are using a older version.

Comment: @uriPopov using the internal builder. Will try updating tomorrow, it's late in the UK. Will feedback thanks for the help so far

Comment: @UriPopov There was a update and has resolved the issue. Pop it as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Unity to the latest stable version. The case is that probably android changed how the icon is represented in the resources and manifest and your version of unity builds the wrong things.